# Get percentage unique numbers generated by random generator

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, random

I am using random generator in my python code. I want to get the percentage of unique random numbers generated over a huge range like from random(0:10^8).I need to generate 10^12 numbers What could be the efficient algorithm in terms of space complexity?
the code is similar to :

```
import random
dif = {}
for i in range(0,1000):
    rannum = random.randint(0,50)
    dif[rannum] = "True"
dif_len = len(dif)
print dif_len
per = float(dif_len)/50
print per
```

Comment: Unique or distinct? In set of { 1,2,1,3 } there are 3 distinct items (1,2,3) and 2 unique (non-duplicate) items (2 and 3)?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen : I want operate on distinct numbers

Comment: Use an array of bits. 12.5MB is required for your range.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of each number the generator generates or there is no way to know whether some new number has been seen before.  What is the best way to do that?  It depends on how many numbers you are going to examine.  For small N, use a HashSet.  At some large number of N it becomes more efficient to use a bitmap.

For small N...

```
public class Accumulator {
   private int uniqueNumbers = 0;
   private int totalAccumulated = 0;
   private HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();

   public void Add(int i) {
     if (!set.Contains(i)) {
       set.Add(i);
       uniqueNumbers++;
     }

     totalAccumulated++;

   }

   public double PercentUnique() {
     return 100.0 * uniqueNumbers / totalAccumulated;
   }
}
```